# Significato di "piccio" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Le banconote gli pesavano nella tasca. Le spenderò tutte oggi – e quando verranno a prendermi non troveranno niente da rubarmi. Cosa vuoi che ti compro, Vita? Caramelle o l’esibizione del lanciatore di coltelli? Una fotografia con lo sfondo di cartapesta o le danze delle tribú africane? Un **piccio**, Diamà, non ne teniamo manco uno. 
>         Diamante consegnò un quarto di dollaro, e si misero in posa davanti all’apparecchio a fisarmonica. Impettiti, con un sorriso forzato sulle labbra.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "piccio" in questo brano? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessuno dei dizionari italiani che ho consultato. Immagino si tratti di un termine di uso regionale, probabilmente correlato al napoletano. Infatti, l'ho trovato sul [Vocabolario napoletano-italiano di Giuseppe Giacco](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1397) col significato di "piagnucolìo", ma questo non sembra avere molto senso nel contesto del passaggio sopra citato.

Comment: Direi che significa “spicciolo”. Voleva farsi una fotografia a un apparecchio automatico, per la quale serviva una moneta.

Comment: @egreg: Adesso me n'accorgo che appare nel [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI13/GDLI_13_ocr_356.pdf) appunto con questo significato. Non è per niente facile fare una ricerca su questo dizionario: scrivi "piccio" nella casella "Ricerca libera" e ti appaiono un sacco di false occorrenze, in modo che finisci per convincerti che il dizionario non contiene questa voce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI13/GDLI_13_ocr_356.pdf) si trova

> **Piccio<sup>2</sup>**, sm. Moneta di poco valore, spicciolo. 
>         *Lomazzi*, 19: Quando alla borsa sentìa qualche piccio. 
>         = Forma apocopata da picciolo<sup>2</sup>.

Quindi, come riportato nel commento di @egreg, il significato sarebbe quello di una moneta di poco valore, cioè, uno spicciolo, di cui avevano bisogno per farsi fare una fotografia.

Answer (score 2):

Si dice anche "spicci" (per dire spiccioli) nel centro sud. Però al singolare, "spiccio", non mi pare di averlo mai sentito. Sembrerebbe una forma collegata. Non conosco questo romanzo, se ho ben capito chi parla sarebbe di Caserta, anche se sono cresciuto a Roma, conosco poco il napoletano, appena quanto basta per seguire Troisi...

Comment: I protagonisti provengono da Minturno.

Comment: A giudicare da [questa mappa](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stato_Pontificio#/media/File:Northern_and_central_Italy_in_1860.jpg) Minturno era praticamente sul confine fra lo stato pontificio ed il regno delle due sicilie . I dialetto locale è molto probabilmente un ibrido di romanesco e napoletano allora

Comment: Secondo [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minturno): "Il dialetto minturnese deriva dalla lingua napoletana ed è influenzato dalla sua variante standard soprattutto a livello prosodico. Il dialetto prevede, quindi, vari elementi lessicali e morfologici campani, ma mescolati ad elementi del Dialetto ciociaro e, in forma minoritaria, del Romanesco."